# How to create entity in Spring Boot so that id remains same

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my *Spring Boot* application let's assume I have a class named `A`:

```
@Entity
public class A{
    @Id
    Long id;
    A(){}       
}
```

And another class named `B` :

```
@Entity
public class B{
    @Id
    Long id;
    A a;
    B(){}       
}
```

What I want is - **whenever I create an instance of B, A gets created with the same id**.

How can I do it ?

Like in JSON, an instance of B:

```
{
   "id": "x",
   "a": {
      "id": "x"
   }
}
```

What I get :

```
{
   "id": "x",
   "a": {
      "id": "y"
   }
}
```

Comment: Set the id? I don't understand your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@OneToOne Mapping with Hibernate shared primary key User - Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732035/onetoone-mapping-with-hibernate-shared-primary-key-user-account)

Comment: Which JPA implementation are you using? Hibernate?

Comment: @Vaidas yes hibernate

Comment: How about using - new A() inside B() and using A.getId() ?

Comment: @AjayKumar not sure but by default it should be `updatable = false`, I encountered error, but didn't read the stack fully ...

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i have updated the que, can you see ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved by using Hibernate's [@MapsId](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html) annotation. There is a good article [here](https://hellokoding.com/jpa-one-to-one-shared-primary-key-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/). I will provide a simplified example bellow:

A class:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private B b;

    ...

}
```

B class:

```
@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn
    @MapsId
    private A a;

    ...

}
```

In this example, the primary key `B.id` is embedded from `A.id`.

Comment: Please see [B is not instantiating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PxnP.png) , although [A is being created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hVQ9.png). I tried to enter via `CommandLineRunner` , please see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD2NX.png)